# как проверить существование адреса сайта на php

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-curl

перед тем как делать запрос на сервер я хотел бы убедится что он существует и если он существует то проверить существование файла на сервере,
при этом вывод в стиле **true** *false*

```
    $ch = '';
    $curl = curl_init($ch);
    curl_exec($curl);
    $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);
```

такой вариант не подходит так как он выводит ошибки на экран
а мне это не нужно
как это сделать ?

```
if (  ) { echo 'сервер не существует'; }
```

Comment: Самый простой способ проверки существования сайта (и того, что он в данный момент доступен, одновременно) - это как раз попытка запроса к нему.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-errno.php, см. пример. Если все же хотите проверить, что сайт существует, попробуйте из URL убрать все пути и параметры запроса и загрузить его главную страницу. Но код при этом будет все равно такой же. "такой вариант не подходит так как он выводит ошибки на экран а мне это не нужно как это сделать ?" - `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно проверять "наличие сайта". Вам нужно сразу запрашивать файл

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/myfile.txt");
$file = curl_exec($curl);
if ($file === false)
  echo curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: все равно на экран выводит File not found без echo

Comment: @skatchmast полный текст ошибки приведите